# maxlags in statsmodels OLS (cov_type='HAC')

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, lag

I want to do a regression with robust standard errors with `cov_type = 'HAC'`. How does the keyword `maxlags` work? If I choose 5 as my maxlags, does it test every every single lagged data point until the fifth is reached and use the one with the best p-values for intercept and coefficient?

So should I just choose a higher value and it automatically gives me the best answer?

And how do I find out the used number of lags afterwards?

My data would be for example:

```
x = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 4, 7, 3, 2]]).T
y = x.shift(1)
```

dropping the first row.

Thank you!

Comment: It uses all lags up to maxlag to compute the relevant covariance matrix.

Comment: Note, `cov_type` does not affect the parameter estimates. It corrects the covariance and standard errors of the parameter estimates for serieal correlation, so we get inference that is robust to serially correlated residuals.

Comment: Okay, thank you. What number should I use for the maxlags then? Does a greater number improve the result in any way?

Comment: Correlation estimates get noisy if (max)lag is large relative to sample size. So, maxlag should not be too large. Otherwise, it depends on for how many periods residuals are correlated, which we can often guess from the subject matter or looking at autocorrelation function or similar.

Comment: I have 1100 data points of monthly returns for one industry. Generally momentum would be strongest for one or even two months. Should I use one or two then as my maximum lag? Or would 10 be a better choice for the max lags (according to this [link](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/ljung-box-test/) )?

Comment: I would go for maxlags=10, and compare with maxlags=5 and maxlags=20 to check whether the standard errors are sensitive to the choice of maxlags. The default kernel downweights correlation at higher lags, so it should be less sensitive to noise than ljung-box.